# How to easily switch between join.me users

Tags: conferencing

Is there an convenient way to make join.me switch the logged in user?  We have it installed in a conference room and it's a pain to constantly log in and out whenever someone different is in there.  Security is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there is current way to quickly switch your logged in join.me user account.

The two suggestions I'd make is consider creating a conference room account which is only used there or consider writing scripts/macros with something like KeePass, perhaps, in order to quickly switch between users.

Sorry they don't really have any options available. I looked in to it last year and came up empty.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this natively, but if security really isn't a problem, Firefox + [the multifox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multifox/) may do what you want. Basically it gives each tab or window its own set of login credentials, so you could have different accounts logged in on each tab (or even set up desktop shortcuts to do it).